# Spring data JPA join table with extra column

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm trying to implement a meeting model which contains multiple equipment entity with corresponding quantity.
In the view of meeting, user should be able to CRUD equipment and quantity of this equipment of a meeting

databases:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS equipment (
  equipment_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  equipment_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meeting (
  meeting_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  meeting_time   TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  number_people  INTEGER      NOT NULL,
  setup          VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meeting_equipment (
  meeting_equipment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
  meeting_id   INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES meeting (meeting_id),
  equipment_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES equipment (equipment_id),
  quantity INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Entity implementation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting")
@Data
public class Meeting {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "meeting_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_time")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime meetingTime;

    @Column(name = "number_people")
    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    private int numberPeople;

    @Column(name = "setup")
    @NotNull
    private String setup;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meeting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    List<MeetingEquipment> equipmentList = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "equipment")
@Data
public class Equipment {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "equipment_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "equipment_name", unique = true)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String equipmentName;
}
```

Join table metting_equipment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_equipment", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"meeting_id", "equipment_id"})})
@Data
public class MeetingEquipment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "meeting_equipment_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_id")
    @NotNull
    @JsonBackReference
    private Meeting meeting;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "equipment_id")
    @NotNull
    private Equipment equipment;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    @NotNull
    private int quantity;
}
```

Using the code above, I can successfully create meeting with equipment included (JSON returned from creation method shows correct content). But once I try to remove an element of equipmentList in meeting entity, it does not delete meetingEquipment entity. I tried 
`meeting.getEquipmentList().clear()` and `meetingEquipmentDao.delete(meeting.getEquipmentList())`, neither works.
Could anyone tell me the cause of this problem, thanks!

Comment: Do I have to create a repository for join table entity?

Comment: what does your debugging tell you? Like does the data get persisted? What code is used to retrieve it? What SQL is issued when you invoke that? Where are the transaction boundaries of your retrieval code? What state are the objects in when retrieving? ...

Comment: @DN1 I'm using JPARepository to do save and retrieve of meeting entity. How do I check the SQL query?

Comment: You chose the jpa provider, so would expect you to know where its docs are

Comment: @JustinKSU I do not understand, please elaborate a bit. Thanks.